# Do not click the ImageButton after the animation

Tags: java, android, arrays, animation, arraylist

I'm developing a puzzle game. The essence of the issue is this. I has buttons `(ImageButton)` in the `ArrayList mButtons` collection and each button has listener, I prescribe an animation of the button for the listener. When I click on the button, the animation works well, BUT !!! if I go back to that button, I can't move it and not press it! As though on top of it the textures were superimposed! Other buttons are pressed. I checked different ways:

```
v.getAnimation().reset();
v.getAnimation().cancel();
v.clearAnimation();
v.setAnimation(null);
v.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(null);
```

did not help! If there are any tips and you have encountered the same issue, please reply!

Picture for understanding:

[image: puzzle]

The code to make it clearer:

```
public class TouchButtonAction implements View.OnClickListener {
private GameController mController;
private List<ImageButton> mButtons;
private List<GridLayout.LayoutParams> mParams;
private final Animation myAnimA;
private volatile  boolean isAnimAFinish = true;

public TouchButtonAction(Context context, GameController controller,             
List<ImageButton> buttons, List<GridLayout.LayoutParams> params) {
this.mParams = params;
this.mButtons = buttons;
this.mController = controller;
this.myAnimA = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.bounce_swap);
final ButtonBounceInterpolator mInterpolatorA = new ButtonBounceInterpolator(0.07, 20);
this.myAnimA.setInterpolator(mInterpolatorA);
//        this.myAnimA.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
     //            @Override
      //            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
      //                isAnimAFinish = false;
    ////                animation.setFillAfter(false);
    ////                animation.reset();
     //
    //            }
    //
     //            @Override
    //            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
   ////                animation.reset();
   //                animation.cancel();
   //                isAnimAFinish = true;
   ////                synchronized (this){
   //
   ////                }
   //            }
   //
   //            @Override
   //            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
   //
   //            }
   //        });

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
int a = mButtons.indexOf((ImageButton) v);

int b = 0;
for (ImageButton button : mButtons) {
    if (!button.isEnabled()) {
        b = mButtons.indexOf(button);
    }
}

if (here check logic) {
    SoundPlay.playSoundPool(SoundPlay.TOUCH);

        if (isAnimAFinish){
   //                    v.post(new Runnable() {
   //                        @Override
   //                        public void run() {
   //                            synchronized (this){
                        v.startAnimation(myAnimA);
                        isAnimAFinish = false;
   //                            }
   //
   //                        }
   //                    });
        }
        if (v.getAnimation() != null){
            if (v.getAnimation().hasEnded()){
                Log.d("LOGGG", "hasEnded Anim");
                v.getAnimation().reset();
                v.getAnimation().cancel();
                v.clearAnimation();
                v.setAnimation(null);
                v.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(null);
                isAnimAFinish = true;

            }
        }


    Collections.swap(mButtons, a, b);
    mController.getGridLayout().removeAllViewsInLayout();
    mController.getGridLayout().removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < mButtons.size(); i++) { // i < 12
        ImageButton button = mButtons.get(i);
        mController.getGridLayout().addView(button, mParams.get(i));
    }

    mController.getGridLayout().invalidate();
} else {
    SoundPlay.playSoundPool(SoundPlay.TOUCH_BANG);
}
mController.checkSolution(mButtons);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was not necessary to use AnimationUtils.loadAnimation (), but quite other classes that allow manipulating objects, such as widgets.

Example animation bouncing button:

```
AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet ();
float y = view.getTranslationY (), distance = 20F;
as.playSequentially (
  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (view, "translationY", y-distance), // animation 1
  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (view, "translationY", y), // animation 2
  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (view, "translationY", y - (distance / 2)), // animation 3
  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (view, "translationY", y)); // animation 4
as.setDuration (600);
as.start ();
```

And the animation of your widget starts to jump. I hope this helped you as much as me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the button after click, then you can use `button.setVisibility(View.GONE)` or if you want, that after click user can't to click that button anymore, you can use after click `button.setClickable(false)`. I think I helped you. If you have questions, ask me.

Comment: You did not understand me. I can not press the button. Because, the button already has another texture. How to remove excess texture?

Answer (score 0):

**How to remove excess texture?** Maybe you can keep two images, one with texture, and another without. Upon clicking first one with texture, hide it and show second one.

Comment: This is not an option. I need to clear the texture. Revert her former condition.